# Error Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData

Tags: matlab, image-processing

While reading a normal image file it is showing this error.
I can use the `imread` command in command window directly but not in the M-file.

I had used the `imread` function like this:

```
 BW=imread('C:\Users\parikh5555\Desktop\books\matlab image\1.jpg')
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
??? Error using ==> image
Error using ==> image
Numeric or logical matrix required for image CData
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is most likely due to the fact that you are trying to use `image` as a variable when it is an actual function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html.

Specifically, you probably ran some code that used `image` as a variable, that variable is now cleared from the MATLAB workspace, and when you are trying to reuse that same M-file script after, it thus spits out that error because `image` is no longer being shadowed as a variable and now it is actually calling the function.

That error has nothing to do with `imread`.  As such, you should go through your M file and make sure you have no variables called `image` and rename them to something else to prevent shadowing over the function unintentionally.

BTW, I'm going to close your question as it's due to a simple typographical error.  Please take no offence.